# How to know size of a nuget package?

Tags: xamarin, nuget, nuget-package

I don't know if it is important for any other project type but for mobile apps size of a nuget package is quite important. Sometimes I want to install a package but I am seeing it has so many other package dependencies, I am thinking is it a big package or not. After installation I can see how big is the package but I couldn't find any possibility, before installation. is it even available on nuget? can we get it maybe with some command on package manager console?

Comment: Xamarin can [fiddle with binaries to remove what's not needed](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12125/exact-behaviour-of-the-linker-in-xamarin-studio). Judge by the final app package size.

Comment: @TimmyJim you mean that I need to program to get the size? is it correct according to the other question?

Comment: @GSerg I know that but sometimes things get messy when you link to much and you just wanna leave package not linked. I had experience this problem earlier and removed many packages and reprogrammed my app. Thats why i am more skeptical before I install any package from nowon